# Is it possible to allow github workflows defined in master branch only?

Tags: github, github-actions

my team has a github repo with some github workflows set up. I noticed that if someone updates a `.github/workflows/[workflow_name].yml` file and push it to a dev branch, the updated workflow definition could also be triggered. I am trying to disallow workflows defined in a dev branch from being picked up, so that any un-reviewed workflow definitions in a dev branch would not be triggered. Is there a way to do that?

Eg. if the yml file in the origin master branch is like

```yaml
on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
    - master
jobs:
  [do_something_here]
```

Then some one updated the yml file to

```yaml
on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
    - master
jobs:
  [do_something_else_instead]
```

and push the code to a dev branch, and make a PR to master branch, at this point no one was requested to review anything, but the `do_something_else_instead` would be triggered.

I want to stop such behavior, only yml files in the master branch should be allowed to trigger workflows.

Answer (score 0):

When you define your workflow to be triggered on a **pull_request** event, you can set a list of branches to be taken into account:

```yaml
on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
    - master
    - 'releases/**'
```

So you can manage which target branch of a PR your workflow is triggered on.

If you want your workflow not to be triggered until a commit is in the master branch, the event you need is **push**. With it, you can also set a branches list, in your case your list would contain only 1 branch: **master**

```yaml
on:
  push:
    branches:
    - master
```

So if your workflow has been modified, **do_something_else_instead** would not be executed until PR is reviewed and merged into **master** branch.

You can a have look on Github documentation here: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions

If you need you can set a mix of filter: **branches**, **branches-ignore**, **paths**, **paths-ignore**, that can be useful :)

Comment: Thanks. I don't mean "pushes to a branch that triggers the workflow", but "triggers the workflow based on the version of yml files in the branch".

Comment: Could you show a piece of code you have please?
What is the event that triggers your workflow?

Comment: Hi Nicolas, I just added some more details to the question description.